# Issue Compiling Botan Using MinGW in Windows7 64bit

Tags: mingw, botan

I am trying to install the non-MSVC version of Botan to my environment. I downloaded the tarball, extracted the files, and ran configure.py

After running configure.py, I run make, make fails with a "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in" error.

What is this error caused by and how do I fix it?

Output from configure.py:

```
INFO: Guessing target OS is windows (use --os to set)
INFO: Guessing to use compiler gcc (use --cc to set)
INFO: Guessing target processor is a x86_64/x86_64 (use --cpu to set)
INFO: Target is gcc-windows-x86_64-x86_64
INFO: Detected gcc version 4.6.1
INFO: Assuming gcc has TR1 (use --with-tr1=none to disable)
INFO: Skipping, by request only - bzip2 cms cvc gnump openssl qt_mutex zlib
INFO: Skipping, dependency failure - sha1_x86_64
INFO: Skipping, incompatible CPU - aes_ni aes_ssse3 md4_x86_32 md5_x86_32 mp_asm64 mp_x86_32 serpent_x86_32 sha1_x86_32 simd_altivec
INFO: Skipping, incompatible OS - alloc_mmap asm_x86_32 asm_x86_64 beos_stats dev_random egd fd_unix proc_walk pthreads unix_procs
INFO: Skipping, incompatible compiler - mp_msvc64 mp_x86_32_msvc
INFO: Skipping, loaded only if needed by dependency - aes_isa_eng mp_generic simd_scalar
INFO: Using MP module mp_x86_64
INFO: Using SIMD module simd_sse2
INFO: ssl: The SSL/TLS code is complex, new, and not yet reviewed, there may be serious bugs or security issues.
INFO: Assuming CPU is little endian
INFO: Assuming unaligned memory access works
INFO: Using copy to link files into build directory
INFO: Botan 1.10.1 build setup is complete
```

Output from make:

```
g++ -m64 -Ibuild\include -O3 -finline-functions  -D_REENTRANT -Wno-long-long -W -Wall -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -c C:\Users\ben.zweber.IPHASE3\Downloads\Botan-1.10.1\src\algo_base\symkey.cpp -o build\lib\symkey.obj
C:\Users\ben.zweber.IPHASE3\Downloads\Botan-1.10.1\src\algo_base\symkey.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
C:\Users\ben.zweber.IPHASE3\Downloads\Botan-1.10.1\src\algo_base\symkey.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [build\lib\symkey.obj] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I seem to have resolved the issue by forcing configure.py to assume a 32bit processor.

```
./configure.py --cpu="i386"
```